# Serialize object to DB and integrity

Tags: mysql, serialization

hello i want serialize my class to DB but i have a questions: how to do an easy referencial integrity?

this is an exsample: artist and his albums 
**one artist to do many albums**:

```
public class Artist{
   int id (primary key)
   String name;
   String surname;
   getAlbums (get all albums from ID **select * from Albums where id = 2,3,4,5** and convert it to Albums class)
   addAlbums (save only ID album into a list)
   removeAlbum (remove an album from Album table)
   public void serializeDB (serialize all this class to DB)      
}

public class Album{
   int id (primary key)
   String name;
   String type; 
   public void serializeDB (serialize all this class to DB)          
}
```

this is table "Artist" (name, surname etc.. serialized to "Value")

PK ID, Sting Value

this is table "Album" (name, type etc.. serialized to "Value")

this tables are separated and not bound..

my question is:
is possible to find my database inconsistent? i have to do a foreingn key into Album table? is it a god way to serialize this data?

Comment: If you want to serialize, don't use a relational database (or at least don't expect database features like foreign key checks still to work).

Comment: I can use foregn Key but i do not understand if it is a Good idea or not..

Comment: I might have misread the question then. Foreign keys are never a bad idea. But doing this with serialized data is only possible with some tricks, so you should not serialize if you want to use the checks provided by the database. If you just use the db to store the data (later), but handle all insert/updates/deletes in your classes, you can do it there. You could still need to check all albums when you delete an artist, or update/delete albums if you delete an artist - so you have to implement your own foreign key check to keep consistency. (But I'm not sure if that is what you are asking).

Comment: Ok and to do stupid join? You can setialize only if you have few data..

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are looking for. Do you want to serialize or not? Serialization and (relational) databases like mysql don't work that well (or at all) together (that means basically everything, like `join`, `where`, foreign keys/indexs, ...). If you just want to store the data (load the whole data into your app, do everything (like `join`, searches, integrity checks) in your class and then save it, and don't need an easy multiuser access), serialization can be an acceptable way (but a simple file would work too). If you e.g. want the db to do integrity checks, don't serialize.